# What shaders should I use to simulate dog fur

Tags: materials, particles, shaders, hair

What shaders for hair particles system material should I use tosimulate dog fur like in the picture below.

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: The Hair BSDF shader would be a good place to start.

Comment: Rephrased your question so it doesn't sound like an opinion based one. For future reference don't ask questions like "what is the best ###" the "best" is always subjective and a matter of opinion.